# Prove that $(a^{-1} ba)^n=a^{-1}b^na$ where $n<0$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have already proved the case where $n>0$ using induction and now im trying to prove $n<0$. The original problem states For any elements $a$ and $b$ from a group and any integer $n$, prove that $(a^{-1}b a)^n=a^{-1}b^na$.

The way I did was I got  $a^{-1}be=a^{-1}b^n$ from $e=b^{-1+n}$and since I let $e=(aa^{-1})^{-n}$ I substituted that for $e$. So I get  $a^{-1}b({aa^{-1}})^{-n}=a^{-1}b^n$. Then it follows by the associative law that $(a^{-1}ba)^{-n}a^{-1}=a^{-1}b^n$ and multiplying on the right by $a$ we get  $(a^{-1}ba)^{-n}=a^{-1}b^na$. I don't think its right because of my beginning assumption but this is what I got after trying to reverse engineer $(a^{-1}b a)^n=a^{-1}b^na$.

Comment: **Hint**: $(a^{-1} b a)^{-1}=\; ?$

Comment: I started off with $e=b^{-1+n}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From $a^{-1}b^{-n}a\cdot a^{-1}b^{n}a=1$ and $(a^{-1}ba)^{-n}\cdot(a^{-1}ba)^n=1$, you get 
$$ a^{-1}b^{-n}a=\left(a^{-1}b^{n}a\right)^{-1}=\left((a^{-1}ba)^n\right)^{-1}=(a^{-1}ba)^{-n}.$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

These equalities should help
 $(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}$ and $(a^n)^{-1}=(a^{-1})^n$

Comment: I take my comment back. Identity is rather fit for things like $\sin^2x+\cos ^2 x=1$, which is an equality that holds true regardless of the value $x$. Equality seems better.

Comment: Ok this is a good distinction between the two terms and personnaly I always believed (and I still) that an identity is an equality or it appears the number one (recall for example the Bezout's identity) and I'm not sure for this definition.